Избавится от инициализации useEffect
У меня есть кастомный хук, задача которого показывать в input типа 'tel' флаг страны исходя из value input.
Такс же есть кастомный Input, который рендерит инпуты разных типов(tel/email/password и т.д) В компоненте Input, я взываю этот самый кстомный хук
const flag = useFlagCountrys(value)

value берет из props
Проблема в том что не важно какого типа инпут, при изменении value в инпуте, происходит иницализация flag. Нужно Добавить в хук проверку на тип инпута, а то на всех инпунтах, при каждом изменении value, у меня пересчитывается флаг.
Никак не пойму как это реализовать
Вот сам хук
export const useFlagCountrys = (value: string) => {
const [flag, setFlag] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    const codeMap = new Map(array.map((item) => [item.code, item.flag]));

    if (value.length <= 4) {
        const flagData = codeMap.get(value);
        if (flagData) {
            setFlag(flagData);
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = Math.min(value.length, 4); i >= 1; i--) {
            const code = value.substring(0, i);
            const flagData = codeMap.get(code);
            if (flagData) {
                setFlag(flagData);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (value.length === 0) {
        setFlag("");
    }
}, [value]);

  return flag;
};

Вот компонент Input
export default function Input({error, extra, className, onChange, type, placeholder, 
    value = '', ...rest
    }: InputProps) {
const flag = useFlagCountrys(value)
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
const handleClick = () => onChange!("")

const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => onChange!(e.target.value)

const handleVisible = () => setVisible(!visible)

switch (type) {
    case 'tel':
        return (
            <Wrapper className={`input ${className || ""}`}>
                {flag.length > 0 && (
                    <p>
                        <img width={17} src={flag} alt={flag}/> +
                    </p>
                )}
                <input
                    {...rest}
                    className="input_types"
                    type="tel"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
            </Wrapper>
        );
    case 'text':
        return (
            <Wrapper className={`input ${className || ""}`}>
                <input
                    {...rest}
                    className="input_types"
                    type="text"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {extra && <div className="extra">{extra}</div>}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    case 'search':
        return (
            <Wrapper className={`input ${className || ""}`}>
                {type === 'search' && (
                    <div className="search_icon flex">
                        <SearchSvg/>
                    </div>
                )}
                <input
                    {...rest}
                    className="input_types"
                    type="search"
                    value={value}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {value?.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="clear_icon pointer" onClick={handleClick}>
                        <ClearInputSvg/>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        );
    case 'password':
        return (
            <Wrapper className={`input ${className || ""}`}>
                <input
                    {...rest}
                    className="input_types"
                    type={visible ? 'text' : 'password'}
                    value={value}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button onClick={handleVisible} className="password_button" type="button">
                    <img
                        src={visible ? "/pic/icons/visible-hide.svg" : "/pic/icons/visible.svg"}
                        alt={visible ? "Hide visible" : "Visible"}
                    />
                </button>
            </Wrapper>
        );
    default:
        return null;
  }
};


Ну так добавьте проверку на тип инпута, в чём проблема?

В этом то и проблема, куда бы я ее не добавил, при изменении value происходит инициализация. Я не могу понять, в какую часть кода ее добавить, чтобы избежать этого

Так у вас в массиве зависимостей указан value, потому он и перезапускается каждый раз, когда вы его меняете
